# Atomic deep merge for document MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to atomically deep merge a document in MongoDB. (I am using Node.js)

For example,
I have this document in my DB -

```
{
    id: 123,
    field1: {
        field2: "abc"
    }
}
```

And I am given this object:

```
{
    field1: {
        field3: "def"
    }
}
```

So I'm looking for my document in the DB to change to this:

```
{
    id: 123,
    field1: {
        field2: "abc",
        field3: "def"
    }
}
```

Of course I can do this in a non-atomic way by:

1. First fetching the document from the DB.
2. Then in JS do the merge and save it to a new object.
3. And finally overwrite the new item to the DB.

But I want this to happen in an atomic matter (so the read and the write stages will not happen separately). Is there any way of doing this?

I have heard the aggregation methods $merge and $mergeObjects might help me with that. Question is - are they atomic?

Thanks all :)

Comment: MongoDB operations are atomic in single document level. If `$mergeObjects` work for you, you can simply use that

Comment: Do you need this to be generic, e.g. given your example doc and a candidate object `{field1: {field3: 'def'},field4: [1,2,3]}` then the merge is `{field1: {field2:'abc',field3: 'def'},field4: [1,2,3]}` in other words taking *all* top level fields under consideration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$function` operator and go recursive.

Consider this doc in the DB:

```
{
    field1: {
        field6: "pre",
        field2: "abc",
        fieldX: {
            aa: [1,2,3],
            bb: "pre",
            cc: "pre"
        }
    }
};
```

This is our candidate merge/overwrite doc:

```
var my_object = {
    field1: {
        field3: "def",
        field6: "post",
        fieldX: {
            bb: "post",
            zz: "post"
        }
    },
    field4: 77,
    field22: "qqq"
};
```

`field4` and `field22` are "easy"; they just get added to the doc.  Where fields exist like `field1`, we have to test for objects vs. non-object.  For objects, we will recursively descend into the db object and the candidate.  For non-objects, we will let the candidate "win" and its value simply overwrites that in the db.  This pipeline:

```js
c = db.foo.aggregate([
    {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$function: {
        body: function(db_object, my_object) {
            var process = function(myo, key, dbo) {
                db_value = dbo[key];

                if(undefined == db_value) {
                    // Easy; db does not have entry at all; just set it:
                    dbo[key] = myo[key];
                    
                } else {
                    // my_value has to be non-null because this function
                    // is driven from the keyset in myo.
                    my_value = myo[key];
                    
                    if(db_value instanceof Object && my_value instanceof Object) {
                        // Both objects with same name; descend!
                        walkObj(db_value, my_value)
                    } else {
                        // my_object "wins" the slot and just overwrites dbo:
                        dbo[key] = myo[key];            
                    }
                }
            };

            var walkObj = function(dbo,myo) {
                // Drive the walk from my_object; it overwrites/appends the db:
                Object.keys(myo).forEach(function(k) {
                    process(myo, k, dbo);
                });
            }

            walkObj(db_object, my_object); // entry point!
            return db_object;
        },
        args: [ "$$CURRENT", my_object ],
        lang: "js"
      }}
    }}

    // Take each doc and put it back using _id as the key:
    ,{$merge: {
        into: "foo",
        on: [ "_id" ],
        whenMatched: "merge",
        whenNotMatched: "fail"
    }}
]);
```

will produce this result in the DB:

```
  {
    _id: ObjectId("63f0f5e45d0b16d1033771e7"),
    field1: {
      field6: 'post',
      field2: 'abc',
      fieldX: { aa: [ 1, 2, 3 ], bb: 'post', cc: 'pre', zz: 'post' },
      field3: 'def'
    },
    field22: 'qqq',
    field4: 77
  }
```